# Color picker not working with undo and redo

Tags: android, canvas, draw, paint, undo

This is the code for implementing undo and redo in Android Canvas and is working fine.

```
package com.example.canva;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;


public class MainView extends View {
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;

private Paint       mPaint;   
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>(); 

public MainView(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();

}
   // im=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //mPath = new Path();
        //canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        for (Path p : paths){
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);


    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        paths.add(mPath);
        mPath = new Path();            

    }

    public void onClickUndo () { 
        if (paths.size()>0) 
        { 
           undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
           invalidate();
         }
        else
        {

        }
         //toast the user 
    }

    public void onClickRedo (){
       if (undonePaths.size()>0) 
       { 
           paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1)); 
           invalidate();
       } 
       else 
       {

       }
         //toast the user 
    }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX();
      float y = event.getY();

      switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              touch_start(x, y);
              invalidate();
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
              touch_move(x, y);
              invalidate();
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
              touch_up();
              invalidate();
              break;
      }
      return true;
    }
   }
```

But in my app I need to change color, stroke width, style etc. when I try to change the Color using the following method, entire thing in the Canvas is changing to that Color.

```
public void setColor(int color){
   mPaint.setColor(color);}
```

Comment: You have to set a path for it. check this complete open source android app   https://github.com/Catrobat/Paintroid It is open source, clip off the code you need for your requirement. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Save the paths in array and perform operations on that array to undo or redo.